# my german red cabbage does not have much liquid. red german cabbage is dry

Tags: cabbage, dry

Is german red cabbage supposed to be dry and if not What do you do if your german red cabbage is dry.

Comment: I’m afraid we need a bit more information - what are you talking about? The plant? A preparation? A dish? Please [edit] your post and clarify.

Comment: Are you referring to the German "sweet & sour cabbage" side dish, (known as Blaukraut or Rotkraut or Rotkohl)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have cooked red cabbage and the result is dry. You want to cover the red cabbage (or any other cabbage) as it cooks to prevent moisture loss, if you aren't covering it then that's the first thing to fix.

There really isn't any magic to it, you just add some water to it as you cook it. Red cabbage, and other cabbages for that matter, don't have that much liquid in them. As they break down they release moisture, much of which will escape out of the pot as it cooks, so you just add a splash now and again to keep it wet enough. You can also use other liquids, I've seen people use wine, I've used apple juice/cider. It all depends on the flavor you want.

Comment: Or, cook it with a lid on the pot to retain the moisture.

Comment: You have a point @gnicko, I am working on the assumption that the poster is covering while cooking as that's the standard method, but you are absolutely right. If the the poster isn't it's one of those 'well thar's yer problem' moments.

Comment: Single-sentence questions kind of force you to start at square one in considering the answer...

Comment: Sorry I did not explain correctly.  I cooked german red cabbage and I did cover it while it cooked but I thought it would have more liquid to it.  I have bought red cabbage in a jar once and it had a lot of liquid.  Next time I will add some wine or water to it.  Thanks for your answers.